# Find two letters at the end of a link and use an IF statement with the match

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I would like to write an IF condition that contains an exact match of letters found in a link, but the way I wrote the if, probably isn't the best method.

Can anyone help me understand better?

The condition to find the letters in the link is written below, but I think it would be better to use a RegEx. How do I write the condition in the if, to contain the RegEx?

```
  const findUrl = "http://wwww.example.com/dk";
```

The IF condition is written like this for now and uses only the `findUrl` variable. How can I write it to use the RegEx for exact matching of `dk` letters?

```
if(findUrl.includes('dk')) {
     // some code here
    }
```

Comment: So, either `/` or end of string after these two letters, right? `/\.com\/(\w{2})(?:\/|$)/`?

Comment: After you've matched the regex `const match = regex.exec(findUrl)` or `const match = findUrl.match(regex)` (the latter only without the `g` flag), you can then use the if-statement `if (match && match[1] == "dk")`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately my answer was rated with -1 but thanks to you it still helped me a lot on my little project